# AVAssetExportSession is not exporting M4V files

Tags: swift, video, avassetexportsession, m4v

I am trying to do an `AVAssetExportSession` with Swift, and I get this error: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid output file type'`. I looked up this error, and it says that for video, Swift only supports QuickTime files, MP4, and AppleM4V, which is weird, because I am trying to export a M4V file. However, I tried exporting an MP4 video, with the filename having the MP4 extension, and the outputFileType being an MP4 file as well, and it worked amazing. I changed it later to all be M4V (Including the video being exported being an M4V file), and it gives me the error. Am I doing something wrong? My code is down below:

```
let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)

        let filename = "filename.m4v"

        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).last!

        let outputURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)

        exporter?.outputURL = outputURL
        exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4V

        exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {

        })
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` only supports .mov files. You have to use `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` instead.

```
let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
```

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/export_preset_names_for_device_appropriate_quicktime_files?changes=latest_minor), `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality`, `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` and `AVAssetExportPresetHighQuality` are for QuickTime .mov files only.

You can find out more by trying to print the contents of the variable `supportedFileTypes` of the `AVAssetExportSession`.

Comment: `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality`, `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` and `AVAssetExportPresetHighQuality` also work for `AVFileTypeMPEG4`